# Cursor position in textbox inside jquery autocomplete callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Autocomplete using css class:-

```
$(cssClass).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    focus: function() {
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var cursorPos = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
        console.log(cursorPos);// showing the proper cursor value
        return false;
    },
    source: function( request, response ){
        var cursorPos = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
        console.log(cursorPos);// undefined ...?
    }
});
```

When I am trying to get the cursor position using css class using jquery autocomplete, in one closure `select` I am able to successfully retrieve the value of current position but when the same is done in `source` closure the value is `undefined`.

Can someone please explain me why is that? and how to get the value?

Comment: You can not expect selectionStart in source as it is only defining the source for autocomplete and user has not yet started his selection

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary what should be the best practice to get this?

Comment: I can not think of any scenario where cursorPos in source can be required. So can not comment.

Answer (score 3):

To get the cursor position inside the **source**, you can try [search event method](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search). This method will be called once you type/change content in the input/text area and then only **source** method will be called. So, what you can do is, have a global variable `cursorPos` and in the **search** method, do the assignment as  `cursorPos = $(this).prop('selectionStart');`
Inside the **source** method, you can get the global variable `cursorPos` value.

Your code can be modified as,

```
var cursorPos; // global var

$(cssClass).autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
focus: function() {
    return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var cursorPos = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
    console.log(cursorPos);
    return false;
},
source: function( request, response ){
    console.log(cursorPos); // refers the global var and returns the cursor pos
    // add your logic
},
search: function( event, ui ){
    cursorPos = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
}
});
```

By this way, you can get the cursor position inside the **source** method :)